# Wget file and send it to Bash

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, wget, pipeline

I want to make a Bash script which has to use [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) and run its output with Bash like this:

```
wget -q -O - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VURksJnn | bash
```

The pastebin file is a test script, but this commands shows me:

"Unknown command" (maybe due to new lines) and "Unexpected end of file", and I don't know why.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script has DOS line-endings.

If you convert the line endings to Unix line endings, it runs fine:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < raw.php\?i\=VURksJnn > script
$ cat script | bash
Test script
You're not root
End test
$
```

Comment: sarnold is right. `wget -q -O - "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VURksJnn" | dos2unix | bash` works fine for me. Outputs ` 
Test script
You're not root
End test
`

Comment: you can still do it in one go: `curl http://script.foo | tr -d '\r' | bash` (or `wget .. -O -`)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not about to execute something from someone else without reading it first. Hence my extra steps. :)

Comment: Just wanted to say that you saved my day!

Answer (score -5):

To start with, you save the downloaded **wget'ed** file locally, and run as `bash filename`. Because the following works for me:

```
cat - | bash
```

Comment: Thanks but the question was about piping the script, even if it's not explicitly mentioned.